# Failed to access the WSDL. It failed with: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: java, webservice, wsdl, jax-rs

He empezado a trabajar con Web Services y al tratar de consumir uno para telefonía proporcionado por Avaya desde una aplicación web que estoy creando en Netbeans. El código en la aplicación es simplemente para un inicio de sesión:

**Código en HTML**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Inicio Sesi&oacute;n</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="login-form" class="login-form" action="index_proceso.jsp" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" id="usuario" required name="usuario" autocomplete="off" >
        </div>                        
        <div>
            <input type="password" class="user-password" placeholder="Contraseña"required name="contrasena" autocomplete="off" >
        </div>                        
        <input id="login-submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Ingresar"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Código en Java desde un JSP**

Estas son las acciones que se realizarán al presionar el botón del inicio de sesión. Aquí es donde mando a llamar al método "createSession" proporcionado por el Web Service que estoy tratando de consumir, este método devuelve un token o identificador tipo cadena si los datos del usuario (usuario y contraseña) son correctos. Por lo que lo único que pido actualmente es que me devuelva e imprima ese token.

```
<jsp:useBean id="valida" scope="request" class="control.Control" />

<%
String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
String contrasena = request.getParameter("contrasena");

System.out.println("DATOS: " + usuario + " " + contrasena);

String resultado = "";
try{
    resultado = valida.createSession(usuario,contrasena);
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

}

System.out.println("TOKEN " + resultado); 
%>
```

**Clase Java donde se importa el método createSession**

```
package control;

import webservices.GenericException;
import webservices.InvalidCredentialsException;


public class Control {

public static String createSession(java.lang.String loginName, java.lang.String password) throws InvalidCredentialsException, GenericException {
    webservices.Directory_Service service = new webservices.Directory_Service();
    webservices.Directory port = service.getDirectory();
    return port.createSession(loginName, password);
}
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al presionar el botón de Ingresar me lanza el siguiente error.

> Failed to access the WSDL at: https://X.XXX.X.XXX:XXXXX/DirectoryWS/Directory?wsdl. It failed with: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present.

He estado investigando como resolver ese error pero no he tenido éxito.
No sé si este error sea debido a algún certificado o porque estoy haciendo mal el consumo del web service. Las funciones y clases se descargaron correctamente pero al tratar de usarlas obtengo el error antes mencionado.

Espero puedan ayudarme a entender la causa de este error y como resolverlo.

Comment: Importa el certificado en un tu keystore de java

Answer (score 2):

En principio la causa relacionada al mensaje es que el servidor `X.XXX.X.XXX` está presentando un certificado (X509) que no tiene declarado el nombre del host en la extensión `SAN` (Subject Alternative Name).

En esta sección del certificado se listan los nombres válidos que puede tener el servidor (y que se usan para contrastar con el nombre ingresado en la URL durante el handshake de TLS).

Tradicionalmenete este control se hacía contra el campo`CN` (Common name), pero en realidad, la sección `SAN`, es el lugar correcto donde debe hacerse la verificación, y esto ultimamente ha comenzado a controlarse en forma más estricta.

Para corroborar que este es el problema podés usar `openssl` para bajar el certificado y revisarlo.

```
echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername X.XXX.X.XXX -connect X.XXX.X.XXX:XXXXX 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text
```

(Ojo, en el `-connect` también está incluido el puerto)

Por ejemplo, esta es la sección de `SAN` corriendo el comando para google.com:443

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.google.com, DNS:*.android.com, DNS:*.appengine.google.com, DNS:*.cloud.google.com,  etc ... (muchos más)
```

[El comando lo tomé de este lugar](https://serverfault.com/questions/661978/displaying-a-remote-ssl-certificate-details-using-cli-tools)

Si este es el problema, lo correcto sería que el certificado se reemplace con uno válido, es decir, que tenga el nombre del host incluido en el `SAN`.

**EDICION I**

Aunque la solución de facto es `opnessl`, enconté que también podés ver el certificado remoto usando `keytool` que viene con la instalación de java.

```
keytool -printcert -sslserver <host>:<puerto>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, me parece una respuesta muy lógica, sin embargo no puedo bajar el certificado con openssl

Comment: Si lo pego tal cual está sustituyendo la IP y el puerto en el cmd obtengo el error "The system cannot find the path specified". Y si abro openssl en el cmd y coloco el comando a partir del "s_client" me sale el mensaje de "unknown option 2>dev/null.

Comment: Si estás usando la version que viene con windows, la mía tampoco funciona. La instalación que en windows me funciona es la que viene con GitBash. Sino fijate si lo podes correr desde una teminal linux o mac.

Comment: Agregué una alternativa para ver el certificado remoto usando keytool.

Comment: Respecto de `"unknown option 2>/dev/null`, en windows `2>/dev/null` sería `2>NUL`